# Nodejs SAML implementation - Not able to get SAML response data

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SAML authentication through nodejs. We got issuer id and assertion url (assume abc.com) from the third party SAML maintenance team.

I have tried both the following two libraries.

https://github.com/lmarkus/passport-saml-encrypted

https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js#note_options

I am facing following issue. Assume i am currently in the url 
http://127.0.0.1:58374/index.html#/home. Now if click login button, it is going to the identity Url. After giving the user credentials, it validates and  directly redirecting to different url abc.com which is given by third-party maintenance team. Whatever callback url, i am giving at backend it didn't use.

My problem is after providing the user credentials, control is not coming back to backend node server where i can fetch SAML response. Just identity portal directly redirects to the given url. So not able to get the SAML response data.

How do i can recieve the SAML response after login validation before re-directing. Kindly share your thoughts.

thanks

r karthik.

Comment: Can anyone provide some idea on how to resolve this and where we are missing..

Comment: any update on this???

Comment: I have resolved it...Basically the problem is the callback URL whatever you specify in library wont get called after authentication..When we are registering with SAML identity provider they will provide one ISSUER ID which we will specify in the library...That ISSUER ID is linked to the URL..That linking is done by the provider..So we can't control it...If we want to route to different URL we need to request SAML identity provider for the new ISSUER ID with the desired link...

Comment: Thanks Karthik... Its really helpful